# Advice on which version of AutoCAD to purchase

Tags: autocad, autocad-map, civil3d

I am starting a consulting agengy and I need to determine what my best interests are regarding the purchase of AutoCAD software.  I have great faith in the more reputable users on this site, and I'm seeking advisement; particularly from those of you who use **both** ESRI software and map capable versions of CAD.

**A little background:** Due to variuos positions I've held in my locale, I have strong expertise in relation to [Mining Land Tunure](http://www.mndm.gov.on.ca/en/mines-and-minerals/applications/claimaps), and the [Aggregate Resources Act](http://www.e-laws.gov.on.ca/html/statutes/english/elaws_statutes_90a08_e.htm) (in Ontario, Canada).  For those of you who are unfamiliar, Aggregate material refers to Pit & Quarry operations (sand, gravel & crushed stone).  Also notewothy, there are a number of Environmental studies associated with these strands for which I provide AutoCAD, GIS, and legislative support.  I leverage GIS and AutoCAD technology interchangably.  I am extremely comfortable going back-and-forth between these two software packages, which allows me to bring a variety of effiiciencies to my worflows. Lastly, I am completely self-taught in AutoCAD, but I have exceptional strength with regard to using it for **my needs**.

**My dilemma** I moved from LDD to Civil 3D a few years ago, and I simply can't imagine going back to a less capable version od AutoCAD now that I've experienced the Cadillac of the AotoCAD realm.  The difference between map 3D and Civil 3D is $5000 +tax per seat.  This is a lot of money at start-up.  I only need a few tools (to my knowledge) from the Civil 3D environment (surface from survey, from .shp, etc).  I don't need most of its functionality (corridors, alignments, etc, etc ................>.  The reseller has indicated that he can give me a few of the Civil tools as part of the Map 3D package, but I have never used it "stand alone".  Otherwise, I need spatial data in CAD for site plans via *mapconnect and mapimport*.  For the most part, it will be shapefiles.

If anyone could advise (who has knowledge of both Civil & map versions) it would be greatly appreciated.  I have done more reading than my schedule can afford.  Will Map 3D meet my needs?  Are there marked differences and shortcomings when measuring Map 3D against the superior product.  I appreciate any advisement.

Answer (score 1):

I've only used Civil3d and it's been a few years so I can't provide any in-depth comparisons. However, you can get a good idea about how the features compare using the online [Autodesk Compare Software tool](http://usa.autodesk.com/compare-autocad-products/). Once you narrow it down, Autodesk offers 30-day free trials.

Comment: Hey Jakub-Thanks for the suggestions (+1 for the effort). I am aware of the different CAD options and the free trial (just never used any besides Civil).I'll be taking a 1 month trial of Map 3D and purchasing it if it meets my needs. The reseller has agreed to throw in a few of the Civil 3D tools I need too. I was looking for feedback related to user experiences with the Map 3D. I will upgrade to thge full Civil 3D package if I find the lesser version is not meeting my needs, but there's a price difference of nearly $6,000 when you factor in taxes and other incidentals. Anyway,thanks again.